# Change data property using checkbox from false to true using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have created list of items in a table. I want to calculate the price of checked items, but can't figure out how to update the data property when a checkbox is checked/unchecked. I have included the code for generating the list and updating the price calculation.

```
$.each(shopList, function (i, elem) {
    var item = elem.item;
    var link = elem.link;
    var user = elem.user;
    var price = elem.price;
    var priority = elem.priority;

    $(".listItems").append(
        '<tr class="items" data-priority="' + priority + '">' +
        '<td><input type="checkbox" class="priority"' + ((priority) ? 'checked' : '') + ' /></td>' +
        '<td>' + '<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + item + '</a>' + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + user + '</td>' +


        '<td class="price">' + price + '</td>' +
        '<td><button class="btn btn-default deleteItem">Del </button></td>' +
        '</tr>'
    );
});
```

And the code to update the price:

```
function updatePriority(){
    sumPriority = 0;
    $('tr.items[data-priority=true] .price').each(function () {

        var total = $(this).text();
        if (!isNaN(total) || total.length != 0) {
            sumPriority += parseFloat(total);
        };
    });
    $('.totalPriority').html(sumPriority.toFixed(2));
};
```

When the page renders it has checked and unchecked items and everything works that way at first, but not when a change is made.
How can I update the data-property true/false in the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Do not use data-property but just use the Checkbox `:checked` status

Instead of looping over the `[data-priority=true]` checkboxes you can loop over the checked checkboxes instead, and use `parent().find('.price')` to find the correct price labels.

```
function updatePriority(){
    sumPriority = 0;
    $('.priority:checked').each(function () {
        var priceElement = $(this).parent().parent().find('.price');

        var total = priceElement.text();
        if (!isNaN(total) || total.length != 0) {
            sumPriority += parseFloat(total);
        };
    });
    $('.totalPriority').html(sumPriority.toFixed(2));
};
```

---

> How can I update the data-property true/false in the DOM?

If you really want to keep your code as it is and only update the `data-priority` attribute when you change a `checkbox` you can implement `change` listeners on the checkboxes and change the parents attribute:

```
$('tr.items .price').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-priority",true);
    }else{
        $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-priority",false);
    }        
});
```

Comment: Sorry I see, you need to take 2 parents in a row, the first is the <tr>

Comment: Yes this works, thank you. It was the second parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

function updatePriority(){
    sumPriority = 0;

```
$('.listItems tr td .priority').each(function () {
     if ($(this).is(":checked"))
     {
        var price=$(this).parent().find('.price').text();
        var total = price;
        if (!isNaN(total) || total.length != 0) {
        sumPriority += parseFloat(total);
        };
     }

});
$('.totalPriority').html(sumPriority.toFixed(2));
```

};